# Tapestry fine-uploader implementation?

Tags: tapestry, fine-uploader

This is a follow-up question to one that I asked in the Tapestry Users mailing list and which Ray Nicholus replied to. The original question:

> Does anyone have a Tapestry implementation that handles uploads with FineUploader 5?
>
> Taha's implementation ( tawus.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/ajax-upload-for-tapestry/ ) looks great, but it's not suited to version 5.0's blobs and its RESTful leanings.

Part of Ray's answer:

> Our setup is fairly simple.  We register a servlet to handle any requests from Fine Uploader (such as the upload and delete requests for traditional endpoints or the signature & success requests for S3 and Azure endpoints)...
>   If you have any further questions, we monitor the fine-uploader tag on stack overflow...

The full response is here: http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/FineUploader-implementation-tt5729640.html

That's great information, Ray. I would like to do the same thing.
Q: Are you using UploadReceiver.java from github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/java?
Q: Can you share your web.xml with us?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> Q: Are you using UploadReceiver.java from github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/java?

The is a starting point for a Java-based endpoint handler.  Any of my projects that integrate Fine Uploader probably have similar code.  That is, a class to handle requests, another to interpret all requests, and a third that specifically parses multipart encoded requests, which is what Fine Uploader sends for file uploads by default.  All of those classes are for traditional endpoints.  If you are using Fine Uploader S3 to upload directly to S3, then the s3/S3Uploads class is a bit simpler since upload requests are sent directly to S3.

> Q: Can you share your web.xml with us?

The web.xml used in any of my Tapestry projects that integrate Fine Uploader is unremarkable.  We do register a `ServletContextListener` in the web.xml that, among other things, maps servlet classes to relative paths.

For example, for this entry in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mydomain.SystemInit</listener-class>
</listener>
```

We will have a `SystemInit` class that implements `ServletContextListener`.  In there we will implement a `contextInitialized` method to map our Fine Uploader request servlet to a specific path like this:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
    ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
    context.addServlet("FineUploaderReceiver", FineUploaderReceiver.class).addMapping("/uploads/*");
}
```

So any requests sent to the path above will hit that class.  Keep that in mind when setting up your client side Fine Uploader options.

In this servlet/receiver, we will inspect the end of the path the determine what type of Fine Uploader request we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but as a side note, it's sometimes beneficial for a tapestry library to run a servlet as a filter within tapestry rather than adding a servlet to the servlet container. This has the added benefit that the servlet init-params can be contributed via MappedConfiguration. Both [tapestry-cometd](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd) and [tapestry-atmosphere](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere) do this.

The following files demonstrate how the AtmosphereServlet is run inside tapestry:

- [HttpServletHttpServletRequestFilter](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/internal/HttpServletHttpServletRequestFilter.java)
- [AtmosphereModule](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/AtmosphereModule.java#L66)
- [AtmosphereHttpServletRequestFilter](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/internal/AtmosphereHttpServletRequestFilter.java)